# Read file line by line and compare with string

Tags: bash

For some or other reason this does not work? I get no output, even though there are no errors and I know the desired line is present.

Please advise on corrections or better alternative.

The "desired line" will be stored as a full file name, i.e /mnt/1.jpg, /mnt/10.jpg, etc. line by line from the directory (using a for loop outside the while loop - disabled for now). The content of posted_text_file will only contain the file names i.e. 1.jpg, 10.jpg, so I assume the lines should be changed containing the directory before it is being compared (compare_line).

The idea is to determine whether a file in the directory is already written up in the text file or not.

```
dir="/mnt"
posted_text_file="$dir/00posted.txt"
nn="desired line"
cat $posted_text_file | while read line
do
    compare_line="$dir/$line"
    if [ "$compare_line" = "$nn" ]
    then
      echo $line #to test
      exit
    fi
done
```

Comment: We need some example file. There might be several reasons why the code does not work. BTW, why not just use the `grep`?

Comment: I tried your code, seems to work fine. The problem must be in your input data. Please check for case differences, leading/trailing spaces, invisible control characters, subtle Unicode differences...

Comment: With your sample setup nn="desired line" will never be equal with compare_line="/mnt/...".

Comment: 00posted.txt will contain lines like 1.jpg, 10.jpg, abc.jpg etc. When I use the while loop (disabled) I will get the names of the files in the directory, but they will be in the form /mnt/1.jpg, /mnt/10.jpg, /mnt/cba.jpg etc. (hence the compare_line). For what it's worth, 00posted.txt was created in windows, but I am able to correctly obtain and display the content of the files correctly in the Linux environment.

Comment: I also think the problem is in the input data. When I echo the input data as $compare_line it shows up line by line on the screen, but for some reason the strings are not compared correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to use this script to post pictures to Fb using cron. The idea is to have a directory with pictures & a text file - to be able to compare the name of the image file to the lines in the text file to see if it was already posted, if not it should post the image and write the image file name to the text file. Using dummy image name lines in the text file, but although the image name is present, the if loop is not triggered. Any help

Comment: Post the output of `xxd 00posted.txt|head` for us to see whether there are special characters.

Comment: Got this in my inbox now again. I (think) I resolved this. The problem was that the 00posted.txt was created in Windows, not Linux.